# Replace string with date in XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am new to C# programming and XML. I wanted to change the string (which starts with @ and end with ') with the date (which I will pick from date picker) Please have a look on below XML file

```
<steps>
  <step1>drop table emp1 purge</step1> 
  <step2>create table emp1 as select e1.first_name ,e1.last_name ,e1.phone_number ,e1.salary     ,e1.hire_date from employees e1 where e1.hire_date between '@m_start_date' to '@m_end_date' group by e1.first_name ,e1.last_name ,e1.phone_number ,e1.salary ,e1.hire_date</step2> 
  <step3>select * from emp1</step3> 
</steps>
```

In the above Xml code I wanted to change @m_start_date with '01-sep-2012' and @m_end_date with '30-sep-2012' The most important point is the strings @m_start_date and @m_end_date are not fixed it my change in other xml file (i.e. it may be @wk_start_dte and wk_end_dte) so I need a logic in C# where we can find a string starts with @ and end with ' so we can replace this string with date.

The expected result should be like this

```
<steps>
  <step1>drop table emp1 purge</step1> 
  <step2>create table emp1 as select e1.first_name ,e1.last_name ,e1.phone_number ,e1.salary     ,e1.hire_date from employees e1 where e1.hire_date between '01-sep-2012' to '30-sep-2012' group by e1.first_name ,e1.last_name ,e1.phone_number ,e1.salary ,e1.hire_date</step2> 
  <step3>select * from emp1</step3> 
</steps>
```

Can you please help me to get this logic in C#?

Comment: Could you give more background? It sounds like you've got named parameters in SQL - so if you're just trying to execute that SQL, you'd be better off just setting the parameter values.

Comment: And adding to Mr Skeet comment, I really suggest you to decide how to name your parameters with identical meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your XML is in a string called test:

```
test = System.Text.RegularExpressions
             .Regex.Replace(test, "'[^']*start[^']*'", "'01-sep-2012'");

test = System.Text.RegularExpressions
             .Regex.Replace(test, "'[^']*end[^']*'", "'30-sep-2012'");
```

Comment: Thanks Skeet and Steve for your response , here is the background for the above query. I am working on tool where I can run my monthly or weekly job through C#. Currently we are importing sql file in toad and replacing old dates with new one and also knowledge of code should be required who is running the job. So I have converted these SQL file into xml with date as named parameters.

Comment: Now I want to show this named parameters as label so user will can understand which date need to pick from date picker and this will go to textbox and finally textbox's date will replace with the named parameter so it will look like my second xml file which I have posted here. So can you please advice me how I can do this? I am trying to convert this xml into string arry where it will find first occurrence of @ and it  go till the next occurrence of ' this I will show as label and date entered in the textbox will replace this string in xml file.

Comment: I trying to apply this logic by using while loop but not getting success as I am new to C# programming. Could  you please help me to build this logic . Thanks.

Comment: This was the answer for your question, though as many people noted you were not explicit, but I could guess what is your problem. This time, I cannot guess, so please, be precise, how do you get your XMLs in your application, where do you store them, etc. BTW, you should mark answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

On top of Ivan's answer about text replacement, probably you will need to do following to find the node

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("yourXml.XML");

XmlNode nodetoChange = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("step2");

string xmlValue = nodetoChange.InnerText;

//Now apply Ivan's logic to replace text as you wish so that xmlValue new text
//then continue to save xml as shown below.

nodetoChange.InnterText = xmlValue;

xDoc.Save(); //In case you need to save it on hard-disk.
xDoc = null;
```

Hope that helps,
Thanks
Milind